# Flushing output stream is ignored in a Servlet under Tomcat via AJP

Tags: java, apache, servlets, mod-jk, ajp

Suppose I have a Java Servlet that takes a while to finish computing it's response, but I'd like the client to see intermediate response rather than wait for it to finish. For example, suppose I have the following doGet code:

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());

    out.println("<h1>The Title</h1>");
    out.flush();

    // ... some computation that takes a while

    // ... now print the result via out

    out.close();
}
```

When I am running Tomcat locally, and accessing the Servlet, I can see the `<h1>` **before** the entire computation is completed.

However, when I run it on my server, and access it via Apache, I only get the response **after** the entire request is completed (in other words, I get a blank screen instead of the `<h1>` which I expect to receive).

I suspect that the issue is somewhere in AJP or Apache, seems like it's ignoring the calls to `flush()`, but I can't seem to find where the problem is.

On the server I'm using Tomcat 6, Apache 2.2.21 and AJP 1.3

Comment: did you try running it on your server without apache to see which product is to blame?

Comment: Tomcat isn't the primary suspect since it "works" on my development machine, but it's true that it would have been best to eliminate it first. Unfortunately I can't access tomcat directly on that server.

Comment: I later tested it on the server without Apache, and it worked - meaning the calls to flush() were not ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out all I needed was to build the APR based Native library for Tomcat. After properly building and installing it based on the instructions [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html), it worked fine with AJP.

Comment: this bug seems to be related : https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41791 . It should be fixed in Tomcat 7.